# Add values to select tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin. I am writing the basic CRUD operations of a application. I can't understand one thing on edit when I try to repopulate the select tag with the selected values it doesn't shows them. I am doing it like this

```
$.each(p["info"]["recievers_id"] , function(key , value){
    $.each(p["users"] , function(key , nextvalue){
        if (value["$id"] == nextvalue["_id"]["$id"]) {
            myData.push({
                id: nextvalue["_id"]["$id"], 
                text: nextvalue["firstname"]
            });
        }
    });
});

$("#messageTo").select2();
$("#messageTo").select2("data", myData, true); //Build my select
$("#messageTo").trigger('change'); //*1* update the values
//If *1* doesn't works use this lines of code:
//$("#messageTo").select2('destroy');
//$("#messageTo").select2();
//$("#messageTo").select2('data', myData, true );
```

The select tag which is using the select2 plugin

```
<div class="form-group">
              <select id="messageTo" class="form-control" data-plugin="select2" multiple="multiple"
              data-placeholder="To:">

              </select>
            </div>
```

is there something that I am doing wrong. I am trying to show the values user had selected at the time of the creation

> [Object]
>
> > 0: Object
> >
> > > id: "569dece31dff7b8416004ae3"
> > >
> > > text: "abc"
> >
> > **proto**: Object
> >
> > length: 1
> >
> > **proto**: Array[0]

Comment: Which version of select2 are you using?

Comment: @Hackerman it's version is  3.4.1

Comment: Add this line at the end of your code: `$("#messageTo").trigger('change');`

Comment: @Hackerman no that doesn't helps either

Comment: @Hackerman is there something that I am doing wrong. I am trying to show the values user had selected at the time of the creation

Comment: I'd highly recommend upgrading to 3.5.4 or 4.0.0 if possible. You are currently using a version of Select2 which is a few years old and is no longer officially supported.

Comment: @KevinBrown I was looking at the wrong file. I am using 4.0.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
var myData = []; //My array of objects to populate the select
$.each(p["info"]["recievers_id"] , function(key , value){
 $.each(p["users"] , function(key , nextvalue){
    if (value["$id"] == nextvalue["_id"]["$id"]) {
        myData.push({
            id: nextvalue["_id"]["$id"], 
            text: nextvalue["firstname"]
        }); //push elements one by one           
    }
 });
});

$("#messageTo").select2();
$("#messageTo").select2("data", myData, true); //Build my select2
```

#### Working fiddle(Updated): https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cnw0q70m/1/

Comment: it throws me this error _The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2._ but the tag to which the id _messageTo_ belongs is using select2 plugin

Comment: I had added the select tag html

Comment: Now it has destroyed it but now it's throwing this error _The select2('data') method was called on an element that is not using Select2._ on this line _$("#messageTo").select2('data', myData );_

Comment: Based on this code, can you show us the result of `console.log(myData);` ?

Comment: Take a look at this code....i'm using your same plugin version: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cnw0q70m/

Comment: I am really sorry but the version I just found out I was using 4.0.1. I was looking at the wrong file

Comment: I update the plugin versions to 4.0.1 and the code target those versions...check now https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cnw0q70m/1/